# How to save a query from model.findOne() on a variable using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell

I am trying to save the results from model.findOne() on a variable for using the results on another function. But what I get on the variable is only a pending promise:

```
let key = Product.findOne({ name: 'keyboard' }).then(data => { return data });
console.log(key);
```

and what I see on mongo shell:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Answer (score 1):

`key` is not the result of findOne(), it is a promise. The promise has not resolved.

To make your example work, change the code:

```
let key = await Product.findOne({ name: 'keyboard' }).exec();
```

Comment: sure, when I use it I'd get a warning that await must be along with async. how can I store the resolved result on a variable for using it in other functions? for example finding an instance and apply a change on it on another function without using general mongoose model methods.

Comment: @MahmoudMirzaei - do you understand what the message **await must be used with async functions** means? It is as simple as declaring your functions like this `async function myFunc() { /* do stuff */ }` If you do not understand async, await and promises, you will have endless problems writing code.

Comment: I am new learner, today just found out we use mongoose static methods like **findMany()** in express and always under http verb functions that could be converted to async functions! Thanks